# How to find the area of the given circle?

Tags: geometry, triangles, circles, area, quadrilateral

Given, we have an $\square ABCD$ with a side length of $1\text{cm}$. We construct its diagonal $AD$. From $C$, we draw the altitude $CE$ of $\triangle ACD$. Now, we construct the altitude $FE$ of the triangle $\triangle CDE$. Now, we connect $F$ and $A$ and name the intersection point on $CE$ to be $G$. We thus formed an $\triangle ACG$. Then, a circle tangent to all the sides of the  $\triangle ACG$ is constructed. What is its area?

[image: Diagram]

### EDIT

---

Well, I could find out some of the lengths of lines and they are as follows:

1. $\overline{AD} = \sqrt{2}$
2. $\overline{ED} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$
3. $\overline{EF} = \frac{1}{2}$
4. $\overline{AF} = \frac{\sqrt{5}}{2}$

Other than this, I have no idea.

Comment: **Hints**: Let we have $AG=a, GF=b, CG=c$ and $GE=d$. Now from triangles $\triangle ACF, \triangle CEF, \triangle AEG$ (all right triangles) and $\triangle EGF$ we can have 4 equation with 4 unknowns $a, b, c$ and $d$. We can find all of them. Hence, for a $\triangle AGC$ we will have/know all three sides, i.e. we will know its area and semiperimeter...

Comment: @AntonVrdoljak we also have $a + b = \frac{\sqrt{5}}{2}$

Comment: There’s actually a purely geometric solution, if you use all of the givens. Remember the circle is tangent to the sides of triangle ACG?

Comment: @AntonVrdoljak sorry to say but i could find only 3 equations ie $a+b = \sqrt{5}/2$, $c+d = 5/\sqrt{2}$, and $\sqrt{(1+2d)/2} = a$

Comment: @Divide1918 I do not have a lot of info on all the rules and laws of maths as I am still in 8th grade.

Comment: @SambhavKhandelwal if you are familiar with trigonometry, use $\tan(\angle FAC) = \tan(\angle AFE)$. Use this to find $\cos(\angle AFE)$ and find a relation between $b$ and $d$. or use $\angle FEG$

Comment: also, $c+d = GC+GE = CE = 1/\sqrt 2$

Comment: To @SambhavKhandelwal: In triangle $\triangle EGF$ it is easy to conclude that $\angle GEF = 45^{\circ}$. Hence, we have (law of cosines) $b^2=d^2 + (0.5)^2-2\cdot d \cdot 0,5\cdot \cos45^{\circ}$. Do you know law of cosines?

Comment: To @SambhavKhandelwal: you term for $a+b$ is correct. Next, D S give a correct term for $c+d$.

Comment: @AntonVrdoljak I have heard of something like that but I do not know what it is.

Comment: To @SambhavKhandelwal: 10 h ago you wrote 3 equations. c+d is not correct, but D S wrote correct one. 8 h ago I wrote 4th equation (follows from law of cosines). That system is solvable. In this moment I have no other idea for some 4th equation...

Comment: @AntonVrdoljak I get your point. But, I have no idea how to work with cosines or anything like that. We have not been introduced to trigonometry yet. If you could provide an answer, I would be grateful to you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We know $AC=1$ which implies $AD=\sqrt{2}$. Next, let we have $AG=a$, $GF=b$, $CG=c\,$ and $\,GE=d$.

Triangle $\triangle ACF$ is right triangle, so we know:

$(a+b)^2 = 1^2 + 0.5^2 \implies \boxed{a+b=\frac{\sqrt{5}}{2}}$.$\qquad (1)$

Triangle $\triangle CFE$ is right triangle, so we know:

$(c+d)^2 = 0.5^2 + 0.5^2 \implies \boxed{c+d=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}}$.$\qquad (2)$

Triangle $\triangle AEG$ is right triangle, so we know:

$a^2 = d^2 + (\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2})^2 \implies \boxed{a=\sqrt{\frac{1+2d^2}{2}}}$.$\qquad (3)$

It is obvious that $EF$ bisects right angle $\angle CED$, so we know angle $\alpha = \angle GEF = 45^{\circ}$. Now we can use law of cosines for triangle $\triangle GEF$. We will have:

$b^2=d^2+0.5^2 - 2\cdot d\cdot 0.5\cdot\cos 45^{\circ}=d^2-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}d+\frac{1}{4}$, i.e.

$\boxed{b=\sqrt{d^2-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}d+\frac{1}{4}}}$.$\qquad (4)$

Adding equations $(3)$ and $(4)$ into equation $(1)$ we can find the value for $d$, i.e. we will find $d \approx 0.2357$. Hence, we can find all other unknowns too. I found $a \approx 0.74536, b \approx 0.37268$ and $c \approx 0.4714$.

Now, since we know all three sides for triangle $\triangle AGC$, we know its perimeter $s=\frac{1+a+c}{2}$ and its area $\Delta=\sqrt{s(s-1)(s-a)(s-c)}$. Hence, we know the radius for its incircle, i.e.
$$
\boxed{r=\frac{\Delta}{s} \approx 0.15037}.
$$

Finally, the required area is:
$$
\boxed{P=r^2\pi \approx 0.07103 \,\, cm^2}.
$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But, I could not understand how we could figure out the radius of the encircle from just the area of the triangle.

Comment: To @SambhavKhandelwal: It is well known formula. See [this reference](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Incircle.html).

Comment: Thanks @AntonVrodoljak!

Comment: You're welcome @SambhavKhandelwal!

Comment: One reason I got confused with this formula for the incircle's area is that i thought the triangle above the $s$ was not the area of the triangle, but the symbol for the delta ie the change. So, i asked for the reference.